# Please help me spot the mistake in design table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have designed a PurchaseOrder table - with partitioning on CreatedDate column - In Visual Studio Data Tool. The codes are shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] (
    [IdGlobal]                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER     NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [IdLocal]                  BIGINT               NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]              DATE                 DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [ApprovedDate]             DATE                 NULL,
    [CreatorID]                BIGINT               NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID]                INT                  NOT NULL,
    [PR_IdGlobal]              UNIQUEIDENTIFIER     NOT NULL,
    [PartnerID]                INT                  NOT NULL,   

    [DeliveryInfo]             VARBINARY(MAX)       NOT NULL,   -- Compressed JsonData

    [Description]              VARBINARY(MAX)       NULL,       -- Compressed Data
    [CurrencyInfo]             NVARCHAR(200)        NOT NULL,   --Json
                                                                    
    [TrackingAccountID]        INT                  NOT NULL,
    [IsImport]                 BIT                  DEFAULT ((0)) NULL, -- Đây là đơn hàng nhập khẩu
    
    [ListItems]                VARBINARY(MAX)       NULL,       -- Compressed JsonList
                                                                
    [ListPaymentTempt]         VARBINARY(MAX)       NULL,       -- Compressed JsonList
                                                                
    [ListItemIDs]              NVARCHAR (200)       NULL,       --Json List of all ItemID in the ListItems -> For reports
    [ListMeasureIDs]           NVARCHAR (200)       NULL,       --Json List of all MeasureID in the ListItems -> For reports

    [DeptApproval]             VARBINARY(200)       NULL,       -- Compressed JsonList
                                                                
    [AccountantApproval]       NVARCHAR(200)        NULL,       --Json
                                                                
    [DirectorApproval]         NVARCHAR(200)        NULL,       --Json
                                                                

    [ValueInfo]                VARBINARY(MAX)       NOT NULL,  -- Compressed JsonData
                                                                
    [CommittionInfo]           VARBINARY(MAX)       NOT NULL,  -- Compressed JsonData
    
    [StockInfo]                VARBINARY(MAX)       NOT NULL,  -- Compressed JsonData
                                                                
    [AcceptanceInfo]           VARBINARY(MAX)       NOT NULL,  -- Compressed JsonData
    
    [PeopleReceiveAlert]       VARBINARY(MAX)       NOT NULL,  -- Compressed JsonList
    
    [Ref]                      VARBINARY(MAX)       NOT NULL,  -- Compressed JsonData

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdGlobal] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PO_CompanyID] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Company] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PO_CreatorID] FOREIGN KEY ([CreatorID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([IdGlobal]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PO_idPR] FOREIGN KEY ([PR_IdGlobal]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PurchaseRequest] ([IdGlobal]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PO_TrackingAccountID] FOREIGN KEY ([TrackingAccountID]) REFERENCES [dbo].TrackingAccount ([Id])
)
--Partion by CreatedDate (Into 120 partition: every 3 months)
ON [3MonthsRangeScheme](CreatedDate)
GO;

--Creat local Index for IdGlobal following partition CreatedDate 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX  [IX_PO_IdGlobal_Partition] ON [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] ([IdGlobal]) ON [3MonthsRangeScheme](CreatedDate)
GO

--Create Index for CreatedDate
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PO_CreatedDate_Partition] ON [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] ([CreatedDate])
GO

--Creat local Index for CompanyID following partition CreatedDate 
CREATE INDEX [IX_PO_CompanyID_Partition] ON [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] ([CompanyID]) ON [3MonthsRangeScheme](CreatedDate)
GO

--Creat local Index for [CreatorID] following partition CreatedDate
CREATE INDEX [IX_PO_CreatorID_Partition] ON [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] ([CreatorID]) ON [3MonthsRangeScheme](CreatedDate)
GO

--Creat local Index for [PartnerID] following partition CreatedDate
CREATE INDEX [IX_PO_PartnerID_Partition] ON [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] (PartnerID) ON [3MonthsRangeScheme](CreatedDate)
GO

--Creat local Index for [PartnerID] following partition CreatedDate 
CREATE INDEX [IX_PO_PR.IdGlobal_Partition] ON [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] (PR_IdGlobal) ON [3MonthsRangeScheme](CreatedDate)
GO

--Creat local Index for [TrackingAccountID] following partition CreatedDate 
CREATE INDEX [IX_PO_PR.TrackingAccountID_Partition] ON [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] (TrackingAccountID) ON [3MonthsRangeScheme](CreatedDate)
GO
```

But when I publish, It always displays error messages like this:

```
Creating Table [dbo].[PurchaseOrder]... (270,1): SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1908, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'CreatedDate' is partitioning column of the index
'PK__PurchaseOrder__8860F3A5'. Partition columns for a unique index
must be a subset of the index key. (270,0): SQL72045: Script execution
error.  The executed script: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] (
    [IdGlobal]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [IdLocal]            BIGINT           NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]        DATE             NOT NULL,
    [ApprovedDate]       DATE             NULL,
    [CreatorID]          BIGINT           NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID]          INT              NOT NULL,
    [PR_IdGlobal]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [PartnerID]          INT              NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryInfo]       VARBINARY (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [Description]        VARBINARY (MAX)  NULL,
    [CurrencyInfo]       NVARCHAR (200)   NOT NULL,
    [TrackingAccountID]  INT              NOT NULL,
    [IsImport]           BIT              NULL,
    [ListItems]          VARBINARY (MAX)  NULL,
    [ListPaymentTempt]   VARBINARY (MAX)  NULL,
    [ListItemIDs]        NVARCHAR (200)   NULL,
    [ListMeasureIDs]     NVARCHAR (200)   NULL,
    [DeptApproval]       VARBINARY (200)  NULL,
    [AccountantApproval] NVARCHAR (200)   NULL,
    [DirectorAp (270,1): SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Could not create
constraint or index. See previous errors. (270,0): SQL72045: Script
execution error.  The executed script: CREATE TABLE
[dbo].[PurchaseOrder] (
    [IdGlobal]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [IdLocal]            BIGINT           NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]        DATE             NOT NULL,
    [ApprovedDate]       DATE             NULL,
    [CreatorID]          BIGINT           NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID]          INT              NOT NULL,
    [PR_IdGlobal]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [PartnerID]          INT              NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryInfo]       VARBINARY (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [Description]        VARBINARY (MAX)  NULL,
    [CurrencyInfo]       NVARCHAR (200)   NOT NULL,
    [TrackingAccountID]  INT              NOT NULL,
    [IsImport]           BIT              NULL,
    [ListItems]          VARBINARY (MAX)  NULL,
    [ListPaymentTempt]   VARBINARY (MAX)  NULL,
    [ListItemIDs]        NVARCHAR (200)   NULL,
    [ListMeasureIDs]     NVARCHAR (200)   NULL,
    [DeptApproval]       VARBINARY (200)  NULL,
    [AccountantApproval] NVARCHAR (200)   NULL,
    [DirectorAp An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
```

I can't seem to spot where the error is coming from. Can anyone help me identify the mistake in my code?

Comment: You need `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CreatedDate, IdGlobal)` if you want to partition it like that. Are you sure you need partitioning, do you actually have many millions of rows?

Comment: @Charlieface: Yes, I need partitioning this table for many millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the  `CreatedDate`  column is used as a partitioning column. But for the index  `PK__PurchaseOrder__8860F3A5`, it is not part of the index key. **The partitioning column must be part of the index key for a unique index.**

To fix this error: While creating `purchaseorder` table, you can add `CreatedDate` along with the `IDglobal` column in the primary key cluster.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] (
    [IdGlobal]                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER     NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [IdLocal]                  BIGINT               NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]              DATE                 DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [ApprovedDate]             DATE                 NULL,
........
.........

 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdGlobal] ASC,[CreatedDate]  ),
 ......
```

Comment: have any otherway to partition this table? I should not make primary key as ([IdGlobal] ASC,[CreatedDate]  ) because of [IdGlobal] is REFERENCES as foreigkey of other table.

Comment: @LeAnhXuan You can make another `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX` just on that column, which the FK can point to, but that does somewhat get in the way of the whole point of partitioning. Or you can change the foreign key to point to both columns.

Answer (score -2):

The error message you provided is related to partitioning a unique index. When partitioning a unique index (clustered or nonclustered), the partitioning column must be chosen from among those used in the unique index key. This restriction enables SQL Server to investigate only a single partition to make sure no duplicate of a new key value already exists in the table. (Reference : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1bcc888d-2f5b-4a6a-99b0-e4a6bf82277d/parition-column-for-a-unique-index-must-be-a-subset-of-index-key?forum=transactsql